# Prove that if $f$ is uniformly continuous then the one sided limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity

If $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $(0,1]$, prove that if $f$ is uniformly continuous, then the one sided limit  $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ exists.

Comment: If the limit exists, then $g$ can be extended to a continuous function on $[0,1]$, and it is therefore uniformly continuous. On the other hand, if $g$ is uniformly continuous, pick any sequence $x_n \to 0$ and show that $\{g(x_n)\}$ is Cauchy. Then prove that its limit is independent of the particular sequence $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: This is the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334779/show-that-f-is-uniformly-continuous-if-limit-exists

Comment: Thanks!, I now know how to prove from right to left. But I still am confused and dont understand the second procedure on sequences. Could you please elaborate on how g(x) is uniformly continuous implies limit existing?

Comment: I was thinking that if g is uniform continuous, g is bounded on (0,1]. Proof by contradiction, assume that g is not bounded. We can find a sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}$ such that $|g(x_n)|\geq n.$
You can extract from $\left\{x_n\right\}$ a Cauchy subsequence since it's a bounded one. |f| is also uniformly continuous hence $\left\{|g(x_n)|\right\}$ is also a Cauchy sequence. We get a contradiction.

Comment: If this doesn’t end up being re-opened, you may want to ask it as a new question.