# Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous if limit exists

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be continuous on $(0,1]$. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous **IFF** $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0^+} f(x)$ exists.

---

Thoughts:

Backward Proof:

Let another function $\overline f(x)$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ which is equal to $f(x)$ plus the limit point. Thus the limit exists and it is uniformly continuous. So, as $f(x)$.

Forward Proof:
I Don't really have any idea...??

Please help guys

Comment: This is the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333901/prove-that-g-is-uniformly-continuous-if-and-only-if-lim-x-to-0-gx-exi

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to show the direction *$f$ uniformly continuous on $(0,1]\Longrightarrow$ the $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$ exists*.

Here are some hints:

- Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence on $(0,1]$ such that $x_n\to 0$. Show that $(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is Cauchy and therefore convergent. Here use the uniformly continuity of $f$.
- If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N},(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are two sequences on $(0,1]$ such that $x_n\to0, \ y_n\to 0$, then by considering the sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ defined as $z_{2k}=x_k$ and $z_{2k+1}=y_k \ \forall k\in\mathbb N$, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(y_n)$.
  (The sequences $f(x_n),f(y_n),f(z_n)$ converge and $f(x_n),f(y_n)$ are subsequences of $f(z_n)$).
- Conclude that the $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$ exists.

Comment: Why do we care about odd and even number $n$  and make up another seqence $y_n$ when you have defined $n\in\mathbb{N}$ on your first hint?

Comment: Because it's a way to show that the limit of $f(x_n)$ is independent of the sequence $\{x_n\}$. You can do that step a different way if you prefer.

Comment: @Paul: In the first hint we show that if $x_n\to0$ then the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges. In the second hint we show that the $\lim f(x_n)$ is independed of the sequence $(x_n)$, i.e. if $x_n\to0$, $y_n\to0$ then $\lim f(x_n)=\lim f(y_n)$.

Comment: @P..) $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy , it is OK. But from here how can you say that  $f(x_n)$ is convergent ? $(0,1]$ is NOT complete.

Comment: @panja717 We show that the limit exist and not that it belongs in $(0,1]$.

Answer (score 4):

A variation of the already-accepted answer: Show that if  $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ does not exist then $f$ is not uniformly continuous: By the definition of $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x),$ if $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ does  not exist then there exists $r>0$ such that for every $\delta\in (0,1)$ there exist $x,y\in (0,\delta)$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|>r.$ Now let  $\epsilon =r.$  There cannot exist $\delta >0$ such that $\forall x,y\in (0,1]\; (|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon)$ .